# Thinking of deploying our vagrant vm to customers, need feedback

Tags: deployment, vagrant, virtualization

We're currently developing a web application and are developing this with vagrant.
We're building our own custom vagrant setup with puphpet for development, and would use a slightly different one with tweaked settings for customers. Is it wise to use vagrant to deploy our application to customers? It would allow for easier deployment and minor configuration. What could be the posisble downsides..apart from the slight overhead of the virtualisation?

Answer (score 1):

what kind of hosting do you have ? why can't you deploy the web app directly on your hosting server ?

I am a big fan of vagrant and uses all the way from development to test and automate things but will not recommend to deploy app on production

The downside that I can think about (I will add if I can think of any):

- security : vagrant is not much secure by default, it can be easily workaround but needs to be taken into account
- monitoring : not sure about your hosting provider but they monitor their instances, all the monitoring of the VM would need to be done by you - the server might be running ok, but your VM not and it will not show in your provider dashboard
- log monitoring : within the VM, all the incoming request will come from the host server, so within apache you will see the NAT address and not the end user IP, so all analytics you could do will loose sense, depending your business this is a big thing. Again it can be somewhat/somehow workaround but to my option there's always downsides.

Comment: hmmn yes I get your point. on the other hand, if we deploy our application directly on the server or deploy the vagrant mahine on the server, the security measures still have to be taken on the server. Monitoring might indeed be a bit trickier. logs however are written in the shared folders so nothing changes there. Thank you for your feedback!